# WINDOW syntax not recognized in MSSQL or DataGrip

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am having a nameless window function, but I want to reuse it. However when I do a named windowed function below the where clause, I cannot get it to work.

I've tested with the [official example](https://learn.microsoft.com/bg-BG/sql/t-sql/queries/select-window-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2017) in both MSSQL and DataGrip. Both fail to recognize the syntax.

My DB is Azure SQL, on the top of the official documentation page it is marked as 'supported'.

This is simplified version of what I am trying to run:

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET Compability_level = 160
GO

USE [MyDB]
GO

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER win AS "Row Number",
FROM Invoices
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY validFrom DESC)
```

The errors I am getting are syntactic ones, I believe the statement does not get executed because it fails to pass some validation chek.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: It's only applicable to SQL Server 2022 and the latest versions of Azure SQL DB (which your database might not yet be on).

Comment: I got it to run - so the DB must support it - but I still have no syntax highlighting in both editors. It is valid SQL, it gets executed, but both editors scream it is syntactically wrong because they don't understand it.

Comment: The "editors" (as you call them) are not the same as the database engine. Don't confuse the two. With time, the querying tools will likely be updated with the knowledge that a certain version of the db engine (all managed SQL Azure and SQL Server 2022) supports this language construct.